# Could not resolve placeholder 'zuul.prefix' in value "${zuul.prefix}"

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-config

I have a project with micro-services of gateway-server(Zuul),eureka-server with integration of config server.

I have a git repository which is having the property file of gateway-server(gateway-server-dev.yml)

gateway-server-dev.yml file:

```
    spring:
    application:
    name: gateway-server

 info:
  component: Gateway Server

endpoints:
 restart:
   enabled: true
 shutdown:
enabled: true
 health:
   sensitive: false



  zuul:
 prefix: /CustomerHub/api
 routes:
   create-customer: 
      path: /create/**
     serviceId: create-customer
   search-customer: 
     path: /search/**
     serviceId: search-customer
   update: 
      path: /update/**
     serviceId: update-customer
   authorization:
     path: /authorization/**
     sensitiveHeaders:
     serviceId: customerhub-authorization      
  host:
       connect-timeout-millis: 5000
       socket-timeout-millis: 10000
        max-total-connections: 10000
       max-per-route-connections: 50
 ribbon:
   eager-load:
     enabled: true

   ribbon:
 ReadTimeout: 60000
 ConnectTimeout: 60000
 MaxAutoRetries: 3
 MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 3
 restclient:
 enabled: true
      eureka:
       enabled: true



eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://{host}:{port}/eureka
    registerWithEureka: true
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true  

hystrix:
  threadpool:
    default:
      coreSize: 1000
      maximumSize: 10000
       queueSizeRejectionThreshold: -1
     maxQueueSize: -1
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
         thread:
              timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

server:
  port: 9000


logging:
  file: /app/logs/aaa_gateway.log
  level:
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    com.customerhub.filters: INFO
    org.hibernate: INFO

customerhub:
  authorization:
    check-token-url: /oauth/check_token
```

And the bootstrap file in gateway-server is:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.application.name=gateway-server
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://{host}:{port}
management.security.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Now when am executing in the eclipse in my local system it is working fine and fetching the properties from config server.

When am running the same jar through the command prompt it is giving the following error:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'zuul.prefix' in value "${zuul.prefix}"

The log file is:

```
2018-11-16 15:08:01.523  INFO 8604 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic 
configuration sources, define System property 
archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties 
available on classpath.
2018-11-16 15:08:01.555  INFO 8604 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is 
initialized with configuration sources: 
com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@ef4443e
2018-11-16 15:08:01.977 ERROR 8604 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. 
Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. 
Message: Error creating bean with name'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration$ZuulFilterConfigur 
  ation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filters'; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'preFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies 
failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not 
resolve placeholder 'zuul.prefix' in value "${zuul.prefix}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring is not able to find the `gateway-server-dev.yml` file so Add your yml file in the classpath using below code on top of your controller.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:gateway-server-dev.yml")
```

OR by adding these lines to the pom under the  section

```
<resource>
     <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     <filtering>true</filtering>
     <includes>
          <include>**/*.yml</include>
     </includes>
</resource>
```

Refer [properties-with-spring](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)

Comment: My .yml file is in git repository. It is giving the following error:  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [gateway-server-dev.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist